# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, unit-testing, graphql, karma-jasmine, apollo

I am testing an angular service that uses Apollo and graphql, I receive **No provider for HttpClient!** Error even though I add HttpClientTestingModule to the imports..

rules.spec.ts

```js
import { PlatformGraphQLService } from 'platform-graphql'
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { RulesService } from './rules.service'
import {
  ApolloTestingModule,
  ApolloTestingController
} from 'apollo-angular/testing'
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'
import { Apollo, ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular'

describe('RulesService', () => {
  let controller: ApolloTestingController
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ApolloTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        PlatformGraphQLService,
      ],
    })
    controller = TestBed.get(ApolloTestingController)
  })

  it('should be created', async(() => {
    const service: RulesService = TestBed.get(RulesService)
    expect(service).toBeTruthy()
  }))


})
```

Comment: Never used this, but I'm reading https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712 and they seem to explicitly declare an injector, and they use HttpTestingController, and not HttpClient directly.

Comment: other interesting example here : https://alligator.io/angular/testing-httpclient/

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still receiving the same error..

Comment: The links in the other comments are bit dated in terms of Angular's current version, so I'd look at this instead: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Answer (score 5):

Normally, providing `ApolloTestingModule`must be enough. I do the same in my article about Apollo testing https://medium.com/@sergeyfetiskin/testing-apollo-graphql-in-your-angular-application-595f0a04aad3 and I do the same in my daily work.

The need of `HTTPClient` can be caused not by Apollo itself but some of your services that uses it directly. So check which service use it and mock that service.

I'm bit surprised that `HTTPClientTestingModule` didn't help but I repeat it's not connected with Apollo.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to import HttpClientModule. Apollo client needs that module to provide HttpClient.